# Emacs org-mode, can agenda not show clocked but show closed?

Tags: emacs, reporting, org-mode

In Emacs org-mode, in the agenda view or Log view, it shows closed and clocked tasks. 
I can press  <kbd>v l</kbd>   to hide both. But I would like to only hide clocked tasks and keep closed tasks. 
The reason is that I want to produce a report of closed tasks, but not list the clocked tasks.

I looked at the [Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html), but could not find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable controlling this is `org-agenda-log-mode-items`:

```
List of items that should be shown in agenda log mode.
This list may contain the following symbols:

  closed    Show entries that have been closed on that day.
  clock     Show entries that have received clocked time on that day.
  state     Show all logged state changes.
Note that instead of changing this variable, you can also press `C-u l' in
the agenda to display all available LOG items temporarily.
```

Setting `(setq org-agenda-log-mode-items '(closed))` will show only closed tasks.